# What should the type be for a subsite widget that can be used in a master site?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have written a Yesod auth plugin that mails out invite codes, which are then required for registration. One thing that I would like to include in the plugin is a widget containing a form for creating invitations; the form would post to a route within the auth plugin. What I'm having trouble with is figuring out a type signature for the widget that allows the creation of the appropriate URL and can also be used within a handler for the master site.

Stripped down to the essentials, the widget looks like:

```
invitationWidget :: GWidget Auth m ()
invitationWidget = do
  tm <- lift getRouteToMaster
  [whamlet|<form action=@{tm inviteR}>|]

inviteR :: AuthRoute
inviteR = PluginR "invite" ["invite"]
```

The trouble is that specifying the `Auth` subsite for the widget means that I can't embed it directly into a handler of type `GHandler master master a` (the exact error is `` Couldn't match type `App' with `Yesod.Auth.Auth' ``). However, if the subsite isn't specified, e.g. `invitationWidget :: GWidget s m ()`, then I don't see a way to get at `inviteR` (the error for that is `Could not deduce (MonadLift (GHandler Auth m) (GWidget s m))`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [addSubWidget](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-core/1.1.3.1/doc/html/Yesod-Widget.html#v%3aaddSubWidget) should be able to help you.